# Can the size of an ArrayList be changed after it is initialized?

Tags: java, arraylist

In a practice test in a class I'm taking there is the following question:

> True or False.  The size of an ArrayList cannot be changed after the ArrayList is initialized.

Immediately looking at the question, I would think the answer would be *false*.  If you initialize an ArrayList, you can continue adding unlimited elements to it and the ArrayList will automatically resize.  However, the answer key claims the answer is *true*.  Why would this be?  Is there something going on behind the scenes that I'm not understanding?

Edit: The instructor told me it was in fact an error in the answer key.  Thank you for all the help.

Comment: It's false. In fact `ArrayList` has a `size()` method so you can try this out yourself.

Comment: Are you sure question is about ArrayList and not simple array?

Comment: Are we talking about a `java.util.ArrayList` or a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`?

Comment: Perhaps the question is referring to being able to change the size explicitly, i.e. with a `setSize(int size)` method or similar, and thus the statement is true since the size parameter is entirely maintained internally.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm wow that's such a poorly worded question, but its possible you might be right.  If so, one of the worst questions I've ever read and this is straight from a previous COMPSCI 201 test at Duke University.

Comment: @JohnFarkerson I would agree to that, it's a terrible question if that's the case, but I know from experience that just because you're in the realm of academia doesn't mean people no longer suck at phrasing their questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

False. To quote from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it explains array list to be a

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

Further it also explains

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically.

Also, for an ArrayList, size can not be set while initializing. However the initial capacity can be set. Size is the number of elements in the list.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I'll definitely be going in to ask for an explanation to this question because the answer they gave makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. setting a value just puts an initial length. if you try to add an element to a "full" List, it will increase in size. only Arrays are fixed in size.

EDIT:

> True or False. The size of an ArrayList cannot be changed after the
>   ArrayList is initialized.

This statement is false. The size can be easily altered by adding more elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remember.. there are 2 things involved.. 
capacity and size..

capacity represents how many max elements the list can
accomodate in it, size represents how many elements are
present currently in the list..the capacity is automatically
increased by certain amount (10, 20, 30..) based on the
current size once the size is equal to capacity..

***In case of the question you have been asked, if this is the code in question, the size cannot be altered... (Common java question)***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a = {1,2,3};
        List l = Arrays.asList(a);
        l.add(4); //error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        System.out.println(l);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be true (in a twisted way), if it takes into account the fact that a new array is created (and the datas of the old one copied into it) in the ArrayList if the size is reached. But it would be like saying that because you replace a part in a computer it's a new one.

I believe you should just go ask for an explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

False, Arraylist in java can be changed all the time when you do add or remove to a element of the list

Answer (score 0):

Size of an Array is not dynamic. It does not grow.

In order to overcome this, Collections has come up with this feature.

ArrayList size is dynamic. If we initialize it with an initial capacity, it would create an arraylist of the same capacity. If the code adds more than the initial capacity, based on the load factor, the size would increase.

Here is an example which explains this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<String>(2);
        arr.add("apple");
        arr.add("apple");
        arr.add("apple");
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
```

No error from the above code. It prints the ArrayList.

**Console Output**

```
[apple, apple, apple]
```

As per your question, when you initialize an Arraylist[here i gave the capacity as 2], size is 0 (i.e. arr.size() is 0) but if you print the size after the Arralylist is assigned with "apple", the size would be 3.